# Error if use subquery in group by : Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have one to one mapping in two tables. For each order there is a purchase, but sometimes purchase are bad so remove association in order table. 
But I need an aggregate table grouped by seller , for which seller how many bad purchases and valid purchases are there.

Examples

```
     Order Table
OrderId     PurchaseId                 
--------    -----------     
  o1            p1
  o2            p6
  o3            null
  o4            p2
  o5            p3



Purchase Table
PurchaseId      OrderId     SellerId
-----------     ---------   ---------
p1              o1          s1
p2              o4          s1
p3              o5          s2
p4              o2          s2
p5              o3          s3
p6              o2          s4

Aggregare Seller Table
SellerId        NullPurchase       validPurchase       TotalPurchase
---------       -------------      --------------      --------------
s1              0                       2               2
s2              1                       1               2
s3              1                       0               1
s4              0                       1               1
```

Query to get aggregate table

```
Select SellerId, count(*) as TotalPurchase,
count(case when ((Select count(*) from dbo.Order where purchaseId = p.PurchaseId) = 0) then 1 end) as NullPurchase
count(case when ((Select count(*) from dbo.Order where purchaseId = p.PurchaseId) = 1) then 1 end) as validPurchase
from dbo.Purchase p
left join on dbo.Order o
on p.OrderId = o.OrderId
group by sellerId
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; remove the `COUNT` functions wrapping your subqueries. (It doesn't make sense to `COUNT` a `COUNT` anyway).

Comment: Also, there's no way your table can be called `Order` and you reference it in the query above without delimit identifying it. `ORDER` is a reserved keyword, and it's strongly recommended you avoid using them as object names, aliases, etc.

Comment: Why dont you use a CTE, Temp table Or sub query and do each stage at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one way to do what you want, if I understand your goal correctly:

```
Select SellerId, count(*) as TotalPurchase,
sum(case when o.purchaseId IS NULL then 1 end) as NullPurchase,
sum(case when o.purchaseId IS NOT NULL then 1 end) as validPurchase
from dbo.Purchase p
left join on dbo.Order o
  on p.OrderId = o.OrderId
  AND p.purchaseId = o.purchaseId
group by sellerId
```

Comment: I have modified my table a bit, the null value for purchase can be replaced in future by another good purchase. In that case will this query work?

Comment: No it needs a small change which I will add.   Okay now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subqueries:

```
select p.SellerId, count(*) as TotalPurchase,
       count(*) - count(o.OrderId) as NullPurchase,
       count(o.OrderId) as validPurchase
from dbo.Purchase p left join 
     dbo.Order o
     on p.OrderId = o.OrderId
group by p.sellerId
```